# Python script to post data to geckoboard

Tags: python, postman, geckoboard

I am looking for help in creating a python script that will push data, specifically to geckoboard in the form of a line graph. Currently the code I have is shown below that has been pulled together from other sources, it would be great if someone could collaborate and help me finish this, I don't know how to insert the values I want on the line graph, if it could be finished with some example values that would be great. Thanks

```
import requests
import json

class Gecko(object):
def __init__(self, api_key):
    self.api_key = api_key

def push(self, widget_key, data):
    ret = requests.post("https://push.geckoboard.com/v1/send/%s" % widget_key, json.dumps({'api_key' : self.api_key, 'data' : data}), verify=False)
    if not (ret.status_code == 200 and ret.json().get('success') == True):
        raise ValueError(ret.content)

def line(self, widget_key, values, **kwargs):
    data = {'item' : [], 'settings' :kwargs}
    for item in values:
        data['item'].append(item)
    return self.push(widget_key, data)

run=Gecko(****************)
print run.push(150634-85f8db34-af52-4fa3-9963-3200a9a6fe74,some_data?)
print run.line(150634-85f8db34-af52-4fa3-9963-3200a9a6fe74,100,'text')
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**
So the biggest issue it seems is forming your JSON payload.  According to the geckoboard API docs, it should look like this:

```
{"api_key" : "some-api-key-goes-here",
 "data": {
     "y_axis": {
         "format": "currency",
        "unit": "USD"
      },
      "series": [
        {
          "name": "GBP -> USD",
          "data": [
            1.62529,
            1.56991,
            1.50420,
            1.52265,
            1.55356,
            1.51930,
            1.52148,
            1.51173,
            1.55170,
            1.61966,
            1.59255,
            1.63762
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
 }
```

During an API call, you basically assemble a JSON payload, then post it to an address with a key.  The widget-key is the unique address or URL that geckoboard wants you to post to, the api_key is your account's key.  The flow you want your program to work in goes like this:
1) Gather your data
2) Assemble your data into a JSON like structure (dictionaries and lists nested)
3) Dump your JSON (This means convert your python specific structure into a JSON structure).
4) Post this JSON to the specific server.

Here is your updated code:

```
import requests
import json

class Gecko(object):
    def __init__(self, widget_key, api_key):

        # You put the widget and api_key values here so you can set it once you
        # call your object and set it.
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.widget_key = widget_key
        self.payload = {
            'api_key' : self.api_key,
            'data' : None
        }

    def push(self):
        ret = requests.post(
            "https://push.geckoboard.com/v1/send/%s" % self.widget_key,
            json.dumps(self.payload),
            verify=False
        )
        if not (ret.status_code == 200 and ret.json().get('success') == True):
            raise ValueError(ret.content)

    # This function is the batteries included version.  It takes all allowable
    # values and checks if they have been provided.  If so, it'll post.
    def line(self, name, data_list, x_axis_labels=None,
             x_axis_type=None, y_axis_format=None, y_axis_unit=None):

        _data = {"series": [{"name": name,
                            "data": data_list}]}

        # Add x_axis to _data if there is an additional param.
        if x_axis_labels is not None or x_axis_type is not None:
            _data["x_axis"] = None

        if x_axis_labels is not None:
            _data["x_axis"]["labels"] = x_axis_labels

        if x_axis_type is not None:
            _data["x_axis"]["type"] = x_axis_type

        # Add y_axis to _data if there are y_axis params.
        if y_axis_format is not None or y_axis_unit is not None:
            _data['y_axis'] = None

        if y_axis_format is not None:
            _data["y_axis"]["format"] = y_axis_format

        if y_axis_unit is not None:
            _data["y_axis"]["unit"] = y_axis_unit

        self.payload["data"] = _data


# Usage:
# Step 1: Form your object and assign it to a variable.  The class now requires
# widget_key and API key to start off with.
line_widget = Gecko(
    widget_key="12345-12315-asfdasdf-asdfasfd",
    api_key="1234-1234-1234-1234")

# Step 2: Add data to the payload:
line_widget.line(name="Something Line graph",
                 data_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                 x_axis_labels=["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"])

# Step 3: Push the data
line_widget.push()
```

Sorry, I can't test to see if the code works right now, but I'm fairly confident it's 95% of the way there.  If you're looking for a simpler way, I built a library that handles forming the JSON and pushing the data to custom widgets on geckoboard.

You can check out [Geckopush](https://github.com/patleeman/geckopush) and let me know if you have any questions.  It's currently at a somewhat stable version now and I'm actively working on it.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

File called test.py

```
import requests
import json

class Gecko(object):
def __init__(self, api_key):
    self.api_key = api_key

def push(self,data):
    ret = requests.post("paste URL here", data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
    if not (ret.status_code == 200 and ret.json().get('success') == True):
        raise ValueError(ret.content)
```

File called test1.py

```
 from test import Gecko
 gecko=Gecko("*************")
 gecko.push({
"api_key": "**************", 
"data": {   
"x_axis": {
        "labels": ["Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4"]
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "data": [
                10000, 13500, 21000, 1900
            ]
        }
    ]
}
})
```